# Mocking generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, mocking, jmock

I am attempting to mock the method below with JMock and I am running into a compiler error.

**Class to Mock:**

```
public interface myClass<T extends SomeClass>{
public void myMethod(T parameter);
public void myOtherMethod();
}
```

**Mock Expectation:**

```
exactly(1).of(myClassMocked).myOtherMethod();
exactly(1).of(myClassMocked).myMethod( with(any(SomeClass.class)) );
```

**Compile Error:**

> The method myMethod(capture#6-of ?) in the type myClass is not applicable for the arguments (SomeClass)

I have attempted switching Object.class with other compatible classes and playing around with the matcher.

I am unable to simply change the method signature, that would be too easy.

The long and short of it is I want to ignore this particular method call but I cannot ignore the entire MyClass mock because it is a service I am using for other tasks in my test method.

**EDIT:**
The fix is to change
`final myClass<?> myClassMocked= mockery.mock(myClass.class);` 
(generic specification suggested by eclipse) to
`final myClass<SomeClass> myClassMocked= mockery.mock(myClass.class);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parametrizing the interface with T means that the type has to be defined at compilation time. The problem is in the way you obtain the `myClassMocked`, that's why it's expecting the "any" wildcard `?`.

You should be mocking a subclass of the `myClass` interface parametrized with a type that `extends SomeClass` for example:

```
public class myClassImpl implements myClass<SomeSubclassOfSomeClass>{
    public void myMethod(SomeSubclassOfSomeClass parameter){...}
    public void myOtherMethod(){...}
}
```

Comment: I was about to refactor my test class when I noticed that when I declare my mock, I was passing it a wildcard. I switched that and everything is working now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.